# Complete Newbie needs pointing in the right direction for iPad app

Tags: ios, ipad

Hi I am a complete newbie and am trying to learn Xcode. What I am trying to do is create a project that has a SplitView. I want to be able to tab Add button and bring up something like a popover where a user can then add contact details. I want a customer name to apair on the left and details to show on the right. A good example of what I want to do is a app called contacts. I have spent hour upon hour watching YouTube videos and searching the Internet but I always run into errors. So far I have a SplitView and a popover working. I can't find out where to go from here. Can you please point me in the right direction so I can learn how this is done.

Comment: Wow, title of the year! Only two relevant words :P

Answer (score 1):

http://developer.apple.com/ios/

Answer (score 1):

The link to the [Apple docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Xcode/Conceptual/iphone_development/000-Introduction/introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007959-CH1-SW1) is not just a silly answer. It's quite relevant.

It's admirable that you want to work on a project to focus your learning. But programming is about more than piecing together bits of code you find.

Rather than spend hours watching YouTube and searching the Internet - try reading the documentation, or get a book on iOS development. There is a learning path you need to follow. MVC, Cocoa and Cocoa-Touch frameworks, Interface Guidelines, memory management, etc. If you try to rush this, you'll just end up frustrated. The Contacts app that you are talking about basically interacts with the [Address Book](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/ContactData/Conceptual/AddressBookProgrammingGuideforiPhone/Introduction.html), and reading about that is probably of some use in what you want to do.

So, to point you in the right direction - Stop trying to rush, and pick up bits of information from the Internet. Read the documentation, get a book, and start at the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

Apple's documentation is rather extensive.

This page is a good place to start for the specific things you mentioned: 
[iPad-Specific Controllers](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/iPadControllers/iPadControllers.html)